# Stopping Form Submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

So, I have a form, i.e.

```
 <form method="post" action="url" blah blah blah">
 <input type="text" name="dollars" id="dollars">
 <input type="text" name="cents" id="cents">
 <input id="checkout" type="submit">
 </form>
```

However, if "dollars and cents" don't meet certain criteria, I want the form to stop and not submit, so I have put in the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkout').click(function () {
        //set variables
        var dollars = $('#dollars').val();
        var cents = $('#cents').val();

        if (dollars < 5 || cents < 5) {
            alert("You can't do that.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

While the alert works fine, the form still submits.  What can I do to make the form not submit?

Comment: I think you wanted to write `<form method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/5ByNn/

`e.preventDefault();` - http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

`e.preventDefault();` api will help you to prevent default behaviour and you can chuck in yopur desired behaviour.

Hope this nails your need `:)`

**code**

```
  $('#checkout').click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         //set variables
         var dollars = $('#dollars').val();
         var cents = $('#cents').val();

         if (dollars < 5 || cents < 5) {

             alert("You can't do that.");
             return false;

         }

     });
```

**html** were missing some closing tags

```
<form action="post">
    <input type="text" name="dollars" id="dollars" />
    <input type="text" name="cents" id="cents" />
    <input id="checkout" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way, since some recommend that the submit button be left as is.

```
$("form_reference").submit(function(){
    // return result depending on your condition
    // true or false
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute `disabled` to your `checkout` if the user hasn't meet the condition.

Answer (score 0):

[***See jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/RK4jh/)

Instead of listening for `click` events, listen for the [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event (on the form). That way, your `return false` does the double duty of canceling the form submission. But to further assuage your doubts, you can also [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on the event when your handler is triggered.

Also, because `#dollars` and `#cents` refer to textboxes, [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is returning strings. Make them integers before your comparison using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {

        var dollars = $('#dollars').val();
        var cents = $('#cents').val();

        // convert to ints, but default to 0
        dollars = (dollars ? parseInt(dollars, 10) : 0);
        cents = (cents ? parseInt(cents, 10) : 0);

        if (dollars < 5 || cents < 5) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("You can't do that.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Also note that for your `<form>`, 'post' is the method, while your url (your-link.php) would be the action. e.g. `<form method="post" action="savePrice.php">`

Answer (score 0):

[**Your code**](http://jsfiddle.net/n8GYN/1/) works fine, your can see from the demo that the form does not get submitted after you click Ok on the alert window, but I'd rather use the `submit` event on the form and pass the `event` object and use `event.preventDefault()`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/n8GYN/)

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="text" name="dollars" id="dollars">
 <input type="text" name="cents" id="cents">
 <input id="checkout" type="submit">
 </form>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkout').closest('form').on('submit',function (e) {
        //set variables
        var dollars = $('#dollars').val();
        var cents = $('#cents').val();

        if (dollars < 5 || cents < 5) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("You can't do that.");
        }
    });
});
```